# "The volume boot has only 0 bytes disk space remaining"

Tags: 12.04, boot

After a recent update, I'm getting an alert saying:

```
The volume boot has only 0 bytes disk space remaining
```

But my computer has plenty of HD space free. Does anyone know how I resolve this. (If it's relevant, I'm using the whole disk encryption feature of the alternate install image for Ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: It really depends on how you installed Ubuntu on your machine. Can you "sudo fdisk -l" in terminal and check whether there is a small partition which is almost full?

Comment: Better still, please run the command 'df -H -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs' without the quotes and paste the output here.

Comment: [This question and answers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot) are related to the problem, and may help.

Comment: apparently a known issue for encrypted partition. answer https://askubuntu.com/a/230942/231504 is great -- works for me. Also, though, please increment the count of affected users in the ubuntu tracker: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unattended-upgrades/+bug/1357093

Answer (score 63):

To list all kernel:
`dpkg --get-selections | grep "linux-image-[[:digit:]].*" | tr "\t" ";" | cut -d ";" -f1`

The results looks somewhat like this:

```
linux-image-3.19.0-7-generic 
linux-image-3.18.0-13-generic  
linux-image-3.16.0-23-generic
```

#### Don't delete all kernels, only old ones!

Next let's remove the 3.16 kernel,
`sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.16.0-23-generic`

and then all unused packages from the system:
`sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: I have some called `extra` too, eg both `linux-image-3.13.0-40-generic` and `linux-image-extra-3.13.0-40-generic`. Can I delete the ones with `extra`?

Comment: This was extremely helpful, but didn't **completely** solve my problem (purging an old kernel was still failing).  I had to manually remove some old kernel files.  I found a few large ones using `find /boot/ -type f | xargs du | sort -n`.  My currently running kernel is `3.13.0-66-generic`, so I'm careful not to delete anything related to that, but I did remove the following : `sudo rm /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-63-generic /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-63-generic`.  Finally, running purge on an old kernel succeeds.

Comment: if you really have 0 bytes free, this won't work as @blong said. you have to manually remove some old vmlinuz file before, because the purge process needs to create some files and, if 0 bytes are left, this fails.

Comment: How do I know which kernels are old? My output is 

linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic
linux-image-4.13.0-26-generic
linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic
linux-image-4.13.0-37-generic
linux-image-4.13.0-38-generic
linux-image-4.13.0-39-generic
linux-image-4.13.0-41-generic
linux-image-4.13.0-43-generic
linux-image-4.8.0-36-generic

Comment: @jacob Run `uname -r` to know what kernel is currently being used.

Answer (score 30):

The cause was indeed old kernel images.
To clean up all I had to do was run one line:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This automatically recognized old kernals and removed them.

Answer (score 9):

It might be that your `/boot` partition has accumulated too many kernel versions while doing upgrades over time. This partition is likely to be separate from your *large* disk partition (mounted as `/`). You can check the `/boot` partition space like this (look for the line with /boot):

```
df -h
```

There is a nice page on [how to remove old kernels](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/RemoveOldKernels).

In short, check your current kernel version, get the list of what is installed, and then apt-get remove the old versions. There is also a "magic" one-liner command on the page that will do all that for you. But use it at your own risk.

Instructions in more detail:

1. Get the current kernel version, **the one you want to keep**:

   ```
   uname -r
   ```
2. Get the list of all kernels installed:

   ```
   dpkg -l | grep linux-image-
   ```
3. Run apt-get remove on the kernels you want to remove. **Not on the latest one**! For example:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove linux-image-2.6.32-22-generic
   ```

More notes:

- `dpkg -l` will tell you the [status of the (kernel) package](https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/status-dpkg-list/) before the package name. 
  For example:

  ```
  rc  linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic  ...
  ii  linux-image-3.13.0-40-generic  ...
  ```

  - "rc" means that the package is **r**emoved and has **c**onfiguration files. These you do not need to remove any more.
  - "ii" means that the package is marked for **i**nstallation and is **i**nstalled

  Based on this, you could list only the kernel packages that are installed:

  ```
  dpkg -l | grep "ii.*linux-image-"
  ```

---

**Alternative solution**, using GUI tool [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/).

Install and go to Computer Janitor, check the System->Old Kernel and System->Unneeded packages, and press Clean.

Answer (score 3):

Use this script so that will remove all other old kernels leaving current version and previous (last 1 kernel version)

```
KERNELMAGES=`ls -lRt /boot/vmlinuz-*| awk -F/ '{print $3}' | grep -v $(uname -r) | sed 1d | sed -e 's/vmlinuz/linux-image/g'`

KERNELHEADERS=`ls -lRt /boot/vmlinuz-*| awk -F/ '{print $3}' | grep -v $(uname -r) | sed 1d | sed -e 's/vmlinuz/linux-headers/g'`

for PURGEKERNEL in `echo $KERNELMAGES $KERNELHEADERS`; do

apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get purge $PURGEKERNEL -y

done
```

Comment: Worked perfect, even when I could not do "Paradiesstaub"s answer from the command line.

Comment: I am getting "Permission denied"...