# Unable to install filezilla in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, dependencies, filezilla

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 filezilla : Depends: libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14) but 1.6.18-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
             Depends: libfilezilla0 but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libgnutls30 (>= 3.4.2) but it is not installable
             Depends: libnettle6 but it is not installable
             Depends: libpugixml1v5 (>= 1.7) but it is not installable
             Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
             Depends: libwxbase3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.2+dfsg) but it is not installable
             Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.2+dfsg) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This post may help https://askubuntu.com/questions/799363/filezilla-the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies

Comment: I tried those answers but didn't work for me

Comment: Phew, it almost looks like you have a mixture of different package versions for different ubuntu versions installed. Is that a fresh ubuntu or did you edit on the sources manually?

Comment: im using ubuntu version 14.04 and didn't edit anything manually. I have installed some video player after that this problem begins.

Answer (score -1):

You can install the package.

make sure the repo sources are up to date

sudo apt-get update

To Install the package:

sudo apt-get install packagename

Once the package determines that you have some missing dependencies, run the following command to fix broken or missing dependencies.

sudo apt-get install -f

Above command will only download the missing dependencies if you have already installed the package.